# Indexing of integer array through characters of a string

Tags: c++

I was doing a problem on dynamic programming. The problem was for printing distinct sub sequences from a given string. So I encounter something which was unknown to me. In that code elements of integer array were accessed via character of a string, (actually that was a vector of int type). So I tried to do the same thing in a new code. It was giving me some output. But I didn't understand that.

I have tried this code on my PC but couldn't understand the output. I want to know the logic behind the output and want to know whether indexing is possible through characters of a string.

```c
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using  namespace std;
int main(){
     string s;
     cin>>s;

     int* last = new int[1000];
      for(int i=0;i<s.length();i++){
        cout<<last[s[i]];
     }    
}
```

When I input something in it, lets say "abcdefgh", it will give me "00000000".
Why and what is this? I don't know what is expected output.

Comment: The line  `int* last = new int[1000];` creates an integer array of size 1000 and initialises it with 0. `s[i]` is a character in the string. `last[s[i]]` will typecast char to int because index needs to be an integer, so 'a' will be 97, 'b' will be 98 and so on (refer [ascii table](http://www.asciitable.com/)). All entries of array are initially 0 so output will be 0.

Comment: I  also tried one more thing. I input a word "tiwai" and reduce the size of array to 4, it gave an output "01001". Can you explain this also? And one more thing how can this statement will initialize int* last = new int[1000] all elements to zero?

Comment: "All entries of array are initially 0 so output will be 0." - This is incorrect, since there is no initialization in code. It can be initialized if `()` or `{}` added after `int[1000]`, but as is it is uninitialized and reading it is Undefined Behavior.

Comment: "reduce the size of array to 4, it gave an output "01001". " - Accessing non-existing elements (what you were doing, since indexes for your string is much bigger) is Undefined Behavior, and anything can happen in that case, any result can't be explained.

Comment: Yeah @sklott is right. It is in-fact Undefined behaviour. My bad on not seeing the missing `()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me explain this to you.

But first, some recommendation. If you do write real code and not for competitive programming, please do never use

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using  namespace std;
```

So, now for basic understanding. A string consists for your eyes of characters or letters. The computer, in its memory cannot store letters. It does only know bits and bytes. So, numbers.

There is a code for which number is associated with what character. One of them is [ASCII](http://www.asciitable.com/)

So, if the computer sends those numbers to an output or printing device, these numbers will be converted to some understandable letters.

In reality a string is an array of numbers. Just nicely wrapped for you. And, a string has an index operator []. If you say s[0], then it will give the first character to you, a number. You can check this by casting the character value to an integer. Simply try `std::cout << static_cast<int>(s[0]);`. And you will see a number.

Now you know that s[i] will give you a number. Then you have an array of int's: "last". And you use the index operator [k] to get the k'th element.

If you write last[s[i]], then, first the inner value is evaluated: s[i]. Let us assume that this was character 'A' which is equal to number 65. This results to last[65] and you will read the 66th element of last.

That is already important to understand.

Now to the array last. (By the way, never use ""arrays" or "new").

```
int* last = new int[1000];
```

"new" will allocate a contiguous memory area of 1000 int's (in nowadays computer systems 4000 bytes) on the heap, so somehwehre in the memory. Where it does that, is out of our control. And those values will have some (randdom) content. The memory area is not initialized. (In my opinion this is wrong, we shoud initialize everthing).

In your case, there are accidently many 0's in it, but sometimes also others.

And if you enter now the string "Hello", then this is equivalent to the numbers 72, 101, 108, 108, 111. With that, you will display, the 72nd, 101st, 108th, 108th and 111th integer value of the integer array last.

Hopy this make things clear.